# javax.mail.session not accesible

Tags: java, email, session

I wanted to use javax.mail.session for a project to send a e-mail. When I try to use the Session class the error "The package javax.mail.session is not accesible". I use eclipse 2022-09 and jdk-18.0.2.1 which I downloaded from the Oracle site. The jdk is located in C:\Program Files\Java. I tried to add requires java.desktop; to my module-info.java file but it didn't worked. Also I tried to use jdk1.8.0_181 for my project but it also does not work.

If there is a better way to send a gmail in java 18 I'm open for solutions.

thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Do you have added the javax.mail jar to your project?

Comment: no i assumed that this is present in javax. If that is the error, I find the error message confusing I'll try it right away

Comment: I added the javax.mail.jar but now i got the error message "The type javax.mail.Session is not accessible"

Comment: looks like the class is located in `javax.mail-api`

Comment: Ok I will have a look and try to inculde the javax.mail-api

Comment: Thank you very much now it works! Should I write a post with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you miss the `javax.mail-api` jar as a dependency in your project.
Add it and it should work.

If you are using maven, you can add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to your `pom.xml`

BTW: `javax.mail-api` has changed to `jakarta.mail-api`